# Angular Form Control Hook to MatAutoCompleteDisabled

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there a way for a form control to hook the state for MatAutoCompleteDisabled instead of polling it like the sample below.
Im looking something that is similar to formControl.ValueChanges

```
//Looking for alternate on this one
[MatAutoCompleteDisabled] = "isDisabled()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the value of the `matAutocompleteDisabled` input using a `FormControl` as the autocomplete panel settings are not part of the `FormControl` itself. The [MatAutocompleteDisabled](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger) indicates if the autocomplete panel is disabled or not.

Comment: yeah i know. thats why im looking for an alternative and have a hook to do the manipulation..